# IntelliJ wrap top level method annotations without wrapping inline annotations

Tags: intellij-idea

Turning on "Wrap always" won't work because it becomes:

```
@Annotation1
public 
@Annotation2 
String something() {
  ...
}
```

And "Do not wrap" becomes:

```
@Annotation1 public @Annotation2 String something() {
  ...
}
```

"Wrap if long" and "Chop down if long":

```
@Annotation1 public @Annotation2
String something() {
  ...
}
```

This is what I want:

```
@Annotation1
public @Annotation2 String something() {
  ...
}
```

Other similar questions do not match the format I'm looking for, and say to select one of the options listed above that don't work for me.

Does anyone know of a way to get the formatter to behave that way? A plugin maybe?

Comment: Nope. I'm not annotating parameters.

Comment: Okay, fair point.  This is a bit peculiar since I don't think I've ever bothered to annotate a return value.  Not sure if IntelliJ has caught up with this styling, or even if it makes sense from a programming standpoint (what metadata were you going to extract from annotating the return value?).

Comment: Agreed, it is strange. It's a styling my team uses, so I'm conforming to it. A concrete example is in a Spring controller. `public @ResponseBody Object something(){ ... }`. I'm aware that the `@ResponseBody` can be placed above, but this is the style the team went with (before I joined, just joined the team).

Comment: Oh, I see.  This *isn't* annotating the return type; it's annotating the entire method.  That makes me feel better (since I was definitely a bit confused about why you'd want to annotate the return type).

Comment: It's a method annotation as far as Java's concerned, but logically the Spring annotation @ResponseBody tells Spring "I want you to do something different with the return value", so it's reasonable to think of it as being a return-value modifier rather than a method-modifier.